# How to find an element with its value property (which is created durin runtime)

Tags: variables, dynamic, selenium-webdriver, runtime.exec

different ways I used to click on that element are,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@value=.,"+NewStateName+"]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".//*[@value=.,'"+NewStateName+"']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.value(NewStateName));
driver.findElement(By.linkText(NewStateName));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,"+NewStateName+")]"));

In above code 'NewStstaeName is a string variable for which the value is dynamically generated during run time.



Error returned:
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector .//*[@value=.,NEWSTATEABC21M] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need quotes around the value of NewStateName, try these:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@value=.,'"+NewStateName+"']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'"+NewStateName+"')]"));
```

The resulting selector will then look like:

> .//*[@value=.,'NEWSTATEABC21M']